# Can we use package push upgrade functionality to push new callback url in the list each time

Tags: managed-package, connected-apps, callback

We have domain like *.example.com . Each of our customer have domains like

1. client1.example.com
2. client2.example.com

Hence the callabck url in out connencted app needs to be added with new url eachtime a new client on boards.

Can we use package push upgrade each time new clients onboards with callabck url list updated with new clients URL .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to change the callback URL in the manner you mentioned for new package push upgrades. See [this document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/connected_app_edit.htm) where it states

> For your convenience, you can update some fields in a connected app
>   and the changes apply immediately to all installed versions of the
>   app. For example, connected app descriptions are immediately updated
>   in each version of the connected app. The following
>   version-independent fields bypass the packaging or installation
>   lifecycle.
>
> Description
>
> Info URL
>
> Logo Image URL
>
> Callback URL

You can though specify multiple callback URLs for every connected app with effect as per [these](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_forcecom_security_connapp_callbackurl.htm) rules.

Here's another [thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/147003/can-a-callback-url-contain-wildcards) which confirms wildcards are not supported.